# Formatting "yesterday's" date in python

Tags: python, datetime, date

I need to find "yesterday's" date in this format `MMDDYY` in Python.

So for instance, today's date would be represented like this:
111009

I can easily do this for today but I have trouble doing it automatically for "yesterday".

Answer (score 512, accepted):

Use [`datetime.timedelta()`](https://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects)

```
>>> from datetime import date, timedelta
>>> yesterday = date.today() - timedelta(days=1)
>>> yesterday.strftime('%m%d%y')
'110909'
```

Comment: If you happen to be working with pandas, you can as well use: `print((pd.to_datetime('Today') - pd.Timedelta('1 days')).strftime('%m%d%y'))`

Comment: If you happen to search for options, you can as well use Pendulum (https://pendulum.eustace.io): pendulum.now().subtract(days=-1).strftime('%m%d%y')

Answer (score 179):

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

yesterday = datetime.now() - timedelta(days=1)
yesterday.strftime('%m%d%y')
```

Answer (score 22):

This should do what you want:

```
import datetime
yesterday = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(days = 1)
print yesterday.strftime("%m%d%y")
```

Comment: Why do you care more about the date for people in UTC offset 0 than the date in the system's local timezone?

Comment: I copied that from my code, in database usage you often care about UTC. Removed the UTC stuff.

Answer (score 12):

all answers are correct, but I want to mention that time delta **accepts negative arguments**.

```
>>> from datetime import date, timedelta
>>> yesterday = date.today() + timedelta(days=-1)
>>> print(yesterday.strftime('%m%d%y')) #for python2 remove parentheses
```

Answer (score 9):

Could I just make this somewhat more international and format the date according to the international standard and not in the weird month-day-year, that is common in the US?

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

yesterday = datetime.now() - timedelta(days=1)
yesterday.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

Comment: Agree that we use a weird date format in the States, but the OP specifically requested that weird format--which in this case is `'%m%d%y'.

Comment: @DaveL17, fair point. I'll leave the answer for all outside US who stumble upon this question.

Answer (score 2):

To expand on the answer given by [Chris](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7917292/7262144)

if you want to store the date in a variable in a specific format, this is the shortest and most effective way as far as I know

```
>>> from datetime import date, timedelta                   
>>> yesterday = (date.today() - timedelta(days=1)).strftime('%m%d%y')
>>> yesterday
'020817'
```

If you want it as an integer (which can be useful)

```
>>> yesterday = int((date.today() - timedelta(days=1)).strftime('%m%d%y'))
>>> yesterday
20817
```