# Python - Get Yesterday's date as a string in YYYY-MM-DD format

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, date, datetime

As an input to an API request I need to get yesterday's date as a string in the format `YYYY-MM-DD`. I have a working version which is:

```
yesterday = datetime.date.fromordinal(datetime.date.today().toordinal()-1)
report_date = str(yesterday.year) + \
   ('-' if len(str(yesterday.month)) == 2 else '-0') + str(yesterday.month) + \
   ('-' if len(str(yesterday.day)) == 2 else '-0') + str(yesterday.day)
```

There must be a more elegant way to do this, interested for educational purposes as much as anything else!

Comment: You can look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1712116/formatting-yesterdays-date-in-python?rq=1 and just modify the format string

Answer (score 225, accepted):

You just need to subtract one day from today's date. In Python  `datetime.timedelta` object lets you create specific spans of time as a [`timedelta` object](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta).

`datetime.timedelta(1)` gives you the duration of "one day" and is subtractable from a `datetime` object. After you subtracted the objects you can use [`datetime.strftime`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) in order to convert the result --which is a date object-- to string format based on your [format of choice](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior):

```
>>> from datetime import datetime, timedelta
>>> yesterday = datetime.now() - timedelta(1)

>>> type(yesterday)
>>> datetime.datetime

>>> datetime.strftime(yesterday, '%Y-%m-%d')
'2015-05-26'
```

Note that instead of calling the `datetime.strftime` function, you can also directly use `strftime` method of `datetime` objects:

```
>>> (datetime.now() - timedelta(1)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
'2015-05-26'
```

As a function:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta


def yesterday(frmt='%Y-%m-%d', string=True):
    yesterday = datetime.now() - timedelta(1)
    if string:
        return yesterday.strftime(frmt)
    return yesterday
```

example:

```
In [10]: yesterday()
Out[10]: '2022-05-13'

In [11]: yesterday(string=False)
Out[11]: datetime.datetime(2022, 5, 13, 12, 34, 31, 701270)
```

Comment: TypeError: strftime() takes at most 1 argument (2 given)

Comment: instead of `strftime`, you can also use `isoformat()`

Answer (score 30):

An alternative answer that uses `today()` method to calculate current date and then subtracts one using `timedelta()`. Rest of the steps remain the same.

https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects

```
from datetime import date, timedelta
today = date.today()
yesterday = today - timedelta(days = 1)
print(today)
print(yesterday)

Output: 
2019-06-14
2019-06-13
```

Comment: **This answer is misleading**. Note that you still have to convert your date objects to string. `print` function automatically prints the date in that format but that doesn't mean the objects are string and formatted that way!

Answer (score 10):

```
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.date.fromordinal(datetime.date.today().toordinal()-1).strftime("%F")
'2015-05-26'
```

Answer (score 6):

Calling `.isoformat()` on a `date` object will give you `YYYY-MM-DD`

```
from datetime import date, timedelta
(date.today() - timedelta(1)).isoformat()
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm trying to use only `import datetime` based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15707574/15982746).

```
import datetime

oneday = datetime.timedelta(days=1)
yesterday = datetime.date.today() - oneday
```