# getting today's and yesterday's date

Tags: python-3.x, date, datetime

I want a code snippet that give today's date and yesterday's date in YYYY-MM-DD format. I know how to extract the current date and here is the code for it:

```py
import datetime
cur_date = datetime.datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

But I do not know how to extract the previous day's date. Is manipulating the current date the only method to do so?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python - Get Yesterday's date as a string in YYYY-MM-DD format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30483977/python-get-yesterdays-date-as-a-string-in-yyyy-mm-dd-format)

Comment: For reference [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta)

Comment: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/843953)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using `timedelta` :

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
yesterday = datetime.today() - timedelta(days=1)
```

Output will be :

```
datetime.datetime(2021, 1, 26, 20, 27, 25, 849797)
```