# Download latest file from an SFTP folder with yesterday's timestamp in its name in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, sftp, pysftp

I know how to connect with SFTP server and get the newest file:

```
with pysftp.Connection(host=host, username=user, password=pass, cnopts=cnopts) as sftp:
    print("Connected")

    sftp.cwd('/path')

    latest = 0
    latestfile = None

    for fileattr in sftp.listdir_attr():
        if fileattr.filename.startswith('Name') and fileattr.st_mtime > latest:
            latest = fileattr.st_mtime
            latestfile = fileattr.filename

    if latestfile is not None:
        localFilePath = '//path/to/download/file.txt'
        sftp.get(latestfile, localFilePath)
```

Now I need to find in `/path` the folder whose name has yesterday's timestamp in format `dd.mm.yyyy` and download the newest file from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just enter the yesterday's folder:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

yesterday = datetime.now() - timedelta(1)
name = datetime.strftime(yesterday, '%d.%m.%Y')

sftp.cwd('/path/' + name)
```

*Based on [Python - Get Yesterday's date as a string in YYYY-MM-DD format](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30483977/850848)*.