# Obtain the datetime object for the previous day at midnight

Tags: python, datetime

I have a `datetime` object in Python, for, let's say, `25/06/2017 11:22:33`. I'd like to find a pythonic way of getting a `datetime` object from that one that would represent `24/06/2017 00:00:00`.

I can think of:

```
day_before = now - datetime.timedelta(days=1,
                                      hours=now.hour,
                                      minutes=now.minute,
                                      seconds=now.second)
```

But I was wondering if there is a more concise way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from datetime import date, timedelta
yesterday = date.today() - timedelta(1)
```

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1712116/formatting-yesterdays-date-in-python).

Comment: This is incorrect as the question is asking for a specific time as well.